# fatal: unable to access 'x.git': Received HTTP code 404 from proxy after CONNECT

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree, sourcetree

When try to pull/push a git repo from Source Tree I was getting this error. After installing and re-installing Source Tree and Git I was still getting the error. 
This was preventing me from updating the git repo or pulling changes. One setting was to blame for the issue.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It turns out the issue was the 'add proxy server configuration to Git/Mercurial' option was ticked under options > network. I'm not sure how this got ticked as it wasn't previously but un-ticking this and saving solved the issue.

Comment: I also had similar issue but previously i used proxy on a different location. That could have changed the sourcetree settings based on global proxy settings.